# Qt5 Deployed QtWebEngine Project Not Playing Html5 Videos

Tags: c++, html, qt, qtwebengine

I'm am unable to play Html5 videos on a deployed `Qt5.4` `QtWebEngine` project. I used the `Fancy Browser` example and built it with `MSVC2013 OpenGL 64bit`, and deployed it using `windeployqt.exe`. Now this right here will work fine but the app won't run on a computer without `Qt5.4`. So to fix this, I create a file in the exe directory called `qt.conf` and inside it I put:

```
[Path]
Prefix=.
```

This will fix the app and allow it to run on other computers without Qt. But then the problem now is that after adding the `qt.conf` file, it can no longer play Html5 videos. Is there a plugin or DLL I'm missing? I've been looking and messing around but can't find it...

Comment: how to deploy on windows? tried many things, the qt.conf didn't help. may you pin out missing steps in between?  (app loads but QWebView still stays blank)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I ended up finding it. `windeployqt` didn't copy the `ffmpegsumo.dll` in the qtwebengine folder inside the plugins directory. But there's one thing with doing that... when you put it there, the app needs the `MSVC` Debug DLLs to run, which isn't really a problem, just an inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Qt 5.5.1 msvc2013 I copy the ffmpegsumo.dll to run directory ,it also can't work

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you earn sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question referencing this one if it will help provide context.